# I had written test case for case switch but i am not able to cover break in the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

This is the code  which I have to test :

```
getTransitionMethod(transition) {
        switch (transition) {
            // ease linear
            case "easeLinear":
                return d3EaseLinear;
                break;
            // easeQuadIn as d3EaseQuadIn,
            case "easeQuadIn":
                return d3EaseQuadIn;
                break;
            // easeQuadOut as d3EaseQuadOut
            case "easeQuadOut":
                return d3EaseQuadOut;
                break;
            // easeQuadInOut as d3EaseQuadInOut
            case "easeQuadInOut":
                return d3EaseQuadInOut;
                break;
            // easeCubicIn as d3EaseCubicIn
            case "easeCubicIn":
                return d3EaseCubicIn;
                break;
            // easeCubicOut as d3EaseCubicOut,
            case "easeCubicOut":
                return d3EaseCubicOut;
                break;
            // easeCubicInOut as d3EaseCubicInOut,
            case "easeCubicInOut":
                return d3EaseCubicInOut;
                break;
            // easePolyIn as d3EasePolyIn,
            case "easePolyIn":
                return d3EasePolyIn;
                break;
```

and this is the snapshot testing done for each case :

```
describe("<ReactSpeedometer caseswitch 1/>", () => {
    const setup = () => {
        const majorProps = {
            needleTransition: "easeLinear",
    
        };
        const wrapper1 = mount(<ReactSpeedometer {...majorProps} />);
        return { majorProps,wrapper1};
    };
    describe("basic snapshot testing", () => {
        const { wrapper1, majorProps } = setup();
        it("should render correctly", () => {
            expect(toJson(wrapper1)).toMatchSnapshot();
        });
    });
});
```

[According to this coverage report, I am not able to cover this break, can someone help me with this , how can I cover this break in my coverage report?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raele.png)

Comment: Under what conditions would you expect the `break` statements to be reached?

Comment: First of all `break` statement never execute here as you are returning the result before that.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding I get it now this break is an unreachable code so I don't have to test it. thank you guys once again.